# Get PyDev to recognize self-made modules for import

Tags: python, import, pydev

[PyDev screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/5NLQ45w.png)

Hi,

the title is quite self-explanatory.

I just imported my entire python program autosub in a PyDev project (confusingly also called autosub). Scripts in the subdirectory autosub/autosub (this is getting ridiculous) often import functions from scripts in the same subdirectory.

But the program is actually ran by executing AutoSub.py in the top-directory (note, there is also a AutoSub.py in subdir but this is not the one I execute from the CL)

I suppose because of this, PyDev gives an error on this. Is there an (easy) way to get PyDev to recognize this and make the errors go away?

Cheers!

Comment: Show us your code (the relevant part anyway)

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear, there is a screenshot link at the top

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you're having problems importing submodules from other submodules within your package. See [_Intra-package References_](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) in the documentation on the proper way to do this.

Comment: OK so based on the documentation I'm using absolute imports. It's like this: AutoSub.py imports script subdirA/X, X then import subdirA/Y. Although Y is in the same folder as X, the main script is in the directory above, so the import statement in X look like they originate from the main script. 
I guess this is standard Python behavior but Eclipse is probably confused because of this. Is there a way to 'tell' Eclipse it has to check the imports based on the main scripts in a different (my case upper) directory?

Comment: nm readding the project seems to have solved the issue somehow...

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, the problem seems to be that the actual package (the folder autosub whith has the `__init__.py`) is inside a folder which does not have an `__init__.py` itself

I.e.: you have: autosub/autosub/autosub, the intermediary one: autosub/autosub should not exist -- so that you have autosub <- project in the pythonpath containing a dir autosub which must have the `__init__.py`.